# How to Switch between Configurations in Google Cloud Platform CLI - Cloud Shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-shell

I have multiple `configurations` created via the `gcloud init` command. How can I switch between `configurations` in the Google Cloud Shell (CLI)?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question but you should be able to `gcloud config configurations list` and `gcloud config configurations activate ...` etc. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/configurations

Comment: To compliment @DazWilkin comment: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-understanding-gcloud-configurations/

Comment: What's your problem? The switch or the persistence of your configurations in Cloud Shell?

Comment: The problem is about switching between configurations when needed. @DazWilkin, your answer works like a charm. Would you mind posting it as an answer, so that it might help someone else too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to:

- `gcloud config configurations list`;
- `gcloud config configurations activate ...`
- etc.

See: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/configurations

> **NOTE** Instead of changing the current config globally, you may also explicitly specify the configuration per command,e.g.:

`gcloud [some-command] --configuration=[your-config]`